# How to use text matching expression in cssSelector to find an element using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

For example: 
To find a link with text "click me" the Xpath is `//a[text()='click me'`.

What should be the equivalent in cssSelector which will be used to identify the same element in firebug and firepath?
 `a[text='click me']` is unable to find the same element.

Please help

Comment: show us the whole HTML, and your xpath expression is incomplete.

Comment: I have never seen an element with text as its property, did you mean innerText?

Comment: Your xpath should be //a[text()='click me'] and please share HTML also.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS and Xpath elements can be find using their attributes like the following:

```
 CSS : tagname[attribute='text']
 CSS : tagname[innerText=’text’] or tagname[textContent=’text’]
 Xpath: tagname[@attribute='value']
```

For any other browser(except FireFox) you can use `tagname[innerText=’text’] i.e a[innerText='linkname']`

For Firefox you can use `tagname[textContent=’text’] i.e, a[textContent='linkname']`